# Step through range in D

Tags: iteration, range, d

Is there a way to create a step in D ranges?
For example, in python, 
    range(1, 10, 2)
gives me

```
        [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

all odds within 1 .. 10

Is there a way to do this in D using foreach?

```
    foreach(x; 1 .. 10) {
 }
```

I know I can use iota(start, end, step), but I also want to add an int to the very beginning and I don't know how to convert type Result to an int.

Comment: What do you mean by "add an int to the very beginning"? And the result of `iota(1, 10, 2)` *is* `int`.

Comment: I'm building an array of primes -> iota(3, 16, 2). I need to append a 2 to the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chain([2],iota(3,16,2));`

[chain](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#chain) concatenates ranges lazily

or you can go the other way around with `filter!q{a==2||a&1}(iota(2,16));`